# Assign fake MAC Address to Wireguard Virtual NIC?

Tags: networking, windows-7, drm, wireguard

This may seem like a bit of an odd question and honestly might not make any sense from a networking perspective. Basically, I have a remote box (Windows 7) with Expensive Commercial Enterprise Software on it that I want to VPN into with wireguard.

So, I installed Wireguard onto it, and was able to remote in easily. However, as soon as I installed Wireguard, the Expensive Commercial Enterprise Software stopped working. After much angst, I figured out the problem:

Expensive Commercial Enterprise Software uses [FlexNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexNet_Publisher) DRM to enforce licenses, and FlexNet scans all the network interfaces and collects the MAC addresses to create a "fingerprint" of the system. But if there's a wireguard interface (with an empty mac address), FlexNet hangs/crashes when it tries to fingerprint the system.

Any way to workaround this or am I SOL?

Without wireguard:

```
$ ./lmutil.exe lmhostid
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2008 Acresso Software Inc. All Rights Reserved.
The FLEXnet host ID of this machine is "989036e152c5"
```

With wireguard:

```
$ ./lmutil.exe lmhostid
(hangs indefinitely)
```